# opengl incorrect model rendering

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, render

I am trying to render some stuff using openGL. It "works" but is rendering my model incorrectly. I have looked at several references, and have been unable to tell what is wrong. Perhaps an openGL guru could point out my error?

I am using several libraries such as tinyobjloader, GLM, GLFW, GLEW, etc. Only the parts related to rendering are presented here. Some of the code is only developed to the point of rendering a single model.

shader.vs

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 norm;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec3 normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 2.0f);
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    normal = norm;
}
```

shader.frag

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 normal;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;

void main()
{
    color = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord);
}
```

graphics.h

```
#include <string>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

class Shader;

class Graphics{
    public:
        Graphics(std::string, uint, uint);
        ~Graphics();
        void render();
        void clearScreen();
        void draw();
        void loadTexture(std::string);
    private:
        GLFWwindow* window = NULL;
};

class Shader{
    public:
        Shader(std::string, std::string);
        void useShader();
        GLuint shaderprogram;
};

class Mesh{
    public:
        Mesh(std::vector<glm::vec3>, std::vector<glm::vec3>, std::vector<glm::vec2>, std::vector<uint>);
        void draw();
    private:
        GLuint VBO = 0;
        GLuint VBO_tex = 0;
        GLuint VBO_normal = 0;
        GLuint VAO = 0;
        GLuint EBO = 0;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
        std::vector<uint> indices;
        std::vector<glm::vec2> textures;
};

Mesh loadModel(std::string);
```

graphics.cpp

```
#include <glog/logging.h>
#include "graphics.h"

#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>

#include "tiny_obj_loader.h"

#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

Graphics::Graphics(std::string name, uint w, uint h){
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL){
        LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to create GLFW window";
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to initialize GLEW";
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
};

Graphics::~Graphics(){
    glfwTerminate();
};

void Graphics::render(){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
};

void Graphics::clearScreen(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
};

GLuint texture;
void Graphics::loadTexture(std::string path){
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);  
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    int width, height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(path.c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

Shader::Shader(std::string vertexstring, std::string fragmentstring){
    GLuint vertexshaderid = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentshaderid = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char* vertercstring = vertexstring.c_str();
    const char* fragmentcstring = fragmentstring.c_str();

    GLint success; GLchar errordata[512];

    glShaderSource(vertexshaderid, 1, &vertercstring, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexshaderid);

    glGetShaderiv(vertexshaderid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshaderid, 1024, NULL, errordata);
        LOG(ERROR) << "Vertex Shader Error: " << errordata;
    };

    glShaderSource(fragmentshaderid, 1, &fragmentcstring, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentshaderid);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshaderid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshaderid, 1024, NULL, errordata);
        LOG(ERROR) << "fragment Shader Error: " << errordata;
    };

    shaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, vertexshaderid);
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, fragmentshaderid);
    glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexshaderid);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentshaderid);
};

void Shader::useShader(){
    glUseProgram(shaderprogram);
};

Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<glm::vec3> v, std::vector<glm::vec3> n, std::vector<glm::vec2> t, std::vector<uint> i){
    vertices = v;
    textures = t;
    normals = n;
    indices = i;

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_tex);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tex);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * textures.size(), &textures[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_normal);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_normal);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * normals.size(), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uint) * indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_normal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tex);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
};

void Mesh::draw(){
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
};

#include <iostream>
Mesh loadModel(std::string path){

    std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
    std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;

    std::string err;
    bool ret = tinyobj::LoadObj(shapes, materials, err, path.c_str());

    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> textures;
    std::vector<uint> indices;

    for(auto shape : shapes){
        std::cout << shape.name << std::endl;
        for(uint i = 0; i < shape.mesh.positions.size(); i+=3){
            glm::vec3 vertex;
            vertex.x = shape.mesh.positions[i];
            vertex.y = shape.mesh.positions[i+1];
            vertex.z = shape.mesh.positions[i+2];
            vertices.push_back(vertex);
        }
        for(uint i = 0; i < shape.mesh.normals.size(); i+=3){
            glm::vec3 vertex;
            vertex.x = shape.mesh.normals[i];
            vertex.y = shape.mesh.normals[i+1];
            vertex.z = shape.mesh.normals[i+2];
            normals.push_back(vertex);
        }
        for(uint i = 0; i < shape.mesh.indices.size(); i++){
            indices.push_back(shape.mesh.indices[i]);
        }
        for(uint i = 0; i < shape.mesh.texcoords.size(); i+=2){
            glm::vec2 vertex;
            vertex.x = shape.mesh.texcoords[i];
            vertex.y = shape.mesh.texcoords[i+1];
            textures.push_back(vertex);
        }
    }

    return Mesh(vertices, normals, textures, indices);
};
```

main - cut down

```
#include "graphics.h"
Graphics graphics("hai", 640, 480);
Shader shader(readFile("shader.vs"), readFile("shader.frag"));
shader.useShader();
graphics.loadTexture("tempTexture.jpg");
Mesh m = loadModel("treeStump.obj");
graphics.clearScreen();
shader.useShader();
m.draw();
graphics.render();
```

[picture of failed render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfmX8.png)

As you can see the texture is not drawn on the model properly but it works in blender, and other programs I have loaded it into. This next picture is of a different angle (and in blender) but it is what it should look like.

[picture of correct render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJyHS.png)

If I need to provide more information please tell me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 components for your texture coordinates, which is typical:

```
glm::vec2 vertex;
vertex.x = shape.mesh.texcoords[i];
vertex.y = shape.mesh.texcoords[i+1];
textures.push_back(vertex);
```

But this does not match the way you specify the attribute:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_tex);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

The second argument to `glVertexAttribPointer()` specifies the number of components in the attribute. In this case, it should be 2 to match the data:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

Also, if you care about performance or power usage at all, you should avoid copying data unnecessarily. I count about 4 copies of the vertex data in your code alone. Add the copies in the OBJ parser, and the ones made by the OpenGL driver, and you'll end up copying the entire vertex data about 7 times before it gets rendered. That's a lot of wasted electrons...